# Angular 6 post data to rest API but returns error 500

Tags: angular

I require to post the data to the rest API but it returns error 500. When I test the API in Postman the API is working.

[image: Postman response]

**authentication.service.ts**

```
register(email: string, fullName: string,contactNo: string) {
    var data = {
        'email' : email,
        'fullName' : fullName,
        'contactNo': contactNo
    };

    return this.http.post<any>(`http://localhost:80/user`, {data})
        .pipe(map(user => {

            JSON.stringify(user);
            return user;
        }));
}
```

Comment: try `return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:80/user', data)`

Comment: status code 500 means a server error. Check the server logs what's wrong.

Comment: Can you please check the request payload in the network tab of chrome developer tools, so which data is going to server, we can check...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are posting an object with a property named data that is set to your object data. Remove the curly braces from around data. Your body looks like

```
{
  data: {
    email: email,
    fullName: fullName,
    contactNo: contactNo
  }
}
```

try

```
register(email: string, fullName: string,contactNo: string) {
    var data = {
        'email' : email,
        'fullName' : fullName,
        'contactNo': contactNo
    };

    return this.http.post<any>(`http://localhost:80/user`, data)
        .pipe(map(user => {

            JSON.stringify(user);
            return user;
        }));
}
```

Comment: if you use httpClient, you needn't use JSON.stringify

Comment: I just copied his code, the JSON.stringify does nothing as it creates a string that instantly falls out of scope as it is not assigned to anything.

Comment: sorry, just I see JSON.stringify near httpClient and I get nervous :)